# Rewriting a complex query using CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, find, models

I quickly wrote a quite complex (in terms of structure) SQL query manually in CakePHP initially, but now I am trying to rewrite it to run withing the CakePHP find method.

```
$sql = "SELECT 
    `users`.`username`,
        (SELECT ROUND(SUM(`divisions`.`amount`), 2)
        FROM `purchases` 
        INNER JOIN `divisions` 
        ON `purchases`.`id` = `divisions`.`purchase_id` 
        WHERE `purchases`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` 
        AND `divisions`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
        AND `purchases`.`group_id` = " . $group_id . " 
    ) AS `owed_to`

    FROM `users` 
    INNER JOIN `memberships` ON `users`.`id` = `memberships`.`user_id` 
    INNER JOIN `groups` ON `memberships`.`group_id` = `groups`.`id`
    WHERE `memberships`.`group_id` =  " . $group_id . "  AND
    `users`.`id` !=  " . $user_id . ";";
```

Because SQL allows you to apply the WHERE filter across the whole query it becomes very simple. In Cake you cannot just go:

```
$results = $this->User->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'Membership.group_id =' => $id
    ),...
```

I have tried setting joins:

```
$joins = array(
    array('table'=>'memberships', 
        'alias' => 'Membership',
        'type'=>'inner',
        'conditions'=> array(
        'Membership.user_id = User.id', 'Membership.group_id' => $id)
    ),
```

Which works OK for a single layer of recursion, but then models related to membership (such as group) are not subject to the filter.

I can only imagine I am doing something completely wrong.

Basically I am confused, any help would be appreciated.

**Futher information**

```
User => HasMany => Purchase, Membership, Division
Membership => BelongsTo => Group, User
Group => HasMany => Membership
Purchase => HasMany => Division
Purchase => BelongsTo => User, Group
Division => BelongsTo => Purchase, User
```

Comment: Mind updating the question with the model relations you already have defined? You might be able to get the whole lot just using the `$containable` - it does deep selective recursions easily.

Comment: first you should edit your post, and put relations of tables in your model in the post.

Answer (score 0):

You can write it like this:

```
$results = $this->User->find('all', array(
  'conditions' => array(
    'Membership.group_id' => $id
),...
```

If User has many Membership and Membership belongs to User, and $this->User->recursive = 1, then it should work